# combinatorial analysis

Tags: combinatorial-number-theory

I'm trying to justify the combination formula in my head. I arrived at the following conclusion: The combination of n different objects taken r is equal to the product of the number of arrangements divided by the number of times in which each case is just a repetition of another in which there is a reversal of position. So I thought: the number of cases where there are these reversals of positions is equal to "r" for the first position (because there are "r" positions) "r-1 " for the second position, because I can't repeat the first one, and so on. until I get to r!. So the formula is:
n!/r!(n-r)!
Is this thought correct?

Comment: Congratulations, you are going to discover the "binomial coefficient"...

Comment: Nailed it.  One minor criticism.  You referred to *reversal* of position.  I had to examine your posting fully to realize that you intended *permutation* of position.